# Is there a MySQL JDBC Exception list that describes what each exception gets thrown for?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jruby

I am looking for a list of exception and what they get thrown for.  I am using this [MySQL JDBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), I am writing this in JRuby, so I am importing the jar.

I am catching what I need so that I can report errors for what I am  doing, but I want to also be able to document what else this error handling might catch.

Comment: Note that each `SQLException` (and subtypes) have SQL state and error code available. Are those the details you are looking for? The actual number of Exceptions is more limited.

Comment: Yes and no, I have to catch specific problems, I just want to  know what else might be caught when I catch those exceptions, but that is something that I will keep in mind.   Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at all the exception that are present in the [`java.sql`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) package. They are listed in the "Exception Summary".

You should not depend on any MySQL JDBC specific classes.

Comment: Thanks you! Why shouldn't I depend on and MySQL JDBC specific classes?